# The Guest user email is not displaying in Sales ->orders tab when he/she is in General group.I am using magento CE 1.9

Tags: orders, customer, group

when a customer is checking out as guest and by default he/she goes into General group.But his email is not showing up Sales -> Orders tab .[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its default behaviur of magento it set guest user id as zero, so you can get all the guest user if you fetch the values from sales tables.

Magento display above email address from `customer` table so you will get any email address for guest users. but you can get it in these three tables `sales_flat_order`, `sales_flat_order_address`, and `sales_flat_quote`,